# Extracting data from JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, list

**Hi everyone!**
I need to get all the names in "streamers", but i really don't know how I can do this.
Maybe you can help me.

Thanks!

**JSON file:**

```
    "streamers": [
        {},
        {
            "name": "One\n\n"
        },
        {
            "name": "Two\n\n"
        },
        {
            "name": "Three\n\n"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does the json module documentation in the Python docs not help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so basically what you can do:

```py
import json

names=[]
with open('data.txt') as json_file:
  dict=json.load(json_file)["streamers"]
  for tuple in dict:
    if "name" in tuple:
      names.append(tuple["name"]
print(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `load` method from [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) module. This function accepts a file handler, particularly a JSON file, then it converts it to a Python dictionary object which you can use right away in your code.

You can refer to the following snippet:

```
import json

f = open('path/to/file/file.json')      # Open the JSON file
dictionary = json.load(f)               # Parse the JSON file
f.close()                               # Close the JSON file

streamers = dictionary['streamers']
print(streamers)
```

#### Output

---

```
[
    {},
    {
        "name": "One\n\n"
    },
    {
        "name": "Two\n\n"
    },
    {
        "name": "Three\n\n"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import json

with open('path/to/file.json') as f:
    names = [x.get("name") for x in json.load(f)["streamers"] if x.get("name")]
    print(names)
```